# how to use android Debug.startMethodTracing() method

Tags: android

I had a fragment where it contains its call back methods. I want to know the method tracing  for instance which method is called when. I tried by calling Debug.startmethodTracing("calc") in onCreateView() and Debug.stopMethodTracing() in onDestroy() method. The "calc" file is created with no data in it.I mean nothing is written into that file. Can any one let me know am I doing any wrong in calling Debug.stopMethodTracing().

Thanks in Advance